# Error: "'PolygonOptions' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value" when building Android app (Node.js + Ionic native)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm trying to create an Ionic native mobile app for android. My markers show up on google maps, that part works. I'd like to show polygons on the map as well.

When I give the ionic cordova build android command in the command prompt, I get this error:

```js
            'PolygonOptions' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value
 here.

     L184:          this.map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions().add(new LatLng(0,1)
, new LatLng(1,2)).strokeColor(Color.RED

[11:36:39]  typescript: C:.../src/pages/home/home.ts, line:
184
            Cannot find name 'Color'.

     L184:  n(new PolygonOptions().add(new LatLng(0,1), new LatLng(1,2)).strokeColor(Color.RED).fillColor(Color.BLUE));

[11:36:39]  typescript: C:.../src/pages/home/home.ts, line:
184
            Cannot find name 'Color'.

     L184:  n(new PolygonOptions().add(new LatLng(0,1), new LatLng(1,2)).strokeColor(Color.RED).fillColor(Color.BLUE));

Error: Failed to transpile program
    at new BuildError (C:...\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts
\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
    at C:...\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.
js:159:20
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at transpileWorker (C:...\node_modules\@ionic\app-script
s\dist\transpile.js:107:12)
    at Object.transpile (C:...\node_modules\@ionic\app-scrip
ts\dist\transpile.js:64:12)
    at C:...\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:1
09:82
    at <anonymous>
```

Relevant part of my home.ts:

```js
import { GoogleMapsProvider } from './../../providers/google-maps/google-maps';

import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  GoogleMapOptions,
  CameraPosition,
  MarkerOptions,
  Marker,
  Polygon,
  PolygonOptions,
  BaseArrayClass,
  LatLng,
  LatLngBounds
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  map: GoogleMap;
  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController)
  { }

  loadPolygons() {
    this.map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions().add(new LatLng(0,1), new 
    LatLng(1,2)).strokeColor(Color.RED).fillColor(Color.BLUE));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
createPolygon(_mpts: ILatLng[]){
    let polygOptions: PolygonOptions = {
      points: _mpts,
      strokeColor: '#e60000',
      strokeWidth: 3,
      visible: true
    };

    this.map.addPolygon(polygOptions).then( (_polyg : Polygon) => {

    }, err => {console.error(err);});
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't work :(
    I called the function like this:  this.createPolygon(new LatLng(0,1);
I got this error:
            Argument of type 'LatLng' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LatLng[]'. Property 'length' is missing in
            type 'LatLng'.

Comment: you are passing an object instead of array

Comment: thank you, it works :) Do you know why mine doesn't work?

Comment: what do you nean it works  and then mine does not work?

Answer (score 0):

To add further info,

The ionic-native PolygonOptions (ref [ionic-native/src/@ionic-native/plugins/google-maps/index.ts](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/196be026ea68aa3371b901d698bb1cf959a2dec5/src/%40ionic-native/plugins/google-maps/index.ts)) is an Interface, which you can't use `new` with. But you can just create an object that **conforms** to the interface. (All properties except `points` have `?` after the name, which means they are optional).

Here's the source from ionic-native,

```js
export interface PolygonOptions {
  /**
   * Pass ILatLng[] to specify the vertixes.
   * You need to contain two points at least.
   */
  points: Array<ILatLng>;

  /**
   * Set true if you want to draw the curve polygon based on the earth
   * (default: false)
   */
  geodesic?: boolean;

  /**
   * Set the stroke color
   * (rgb, rgba, #RRGGBB, "colorname", ...etc)
   */
  strokeColor?: string;

  /**
   * Set the stroke width in pixel
   */
  strokeWidth?: number;

  /**
   * Set the inside color of polygon
   * (rgb, rgba, #RRGGBB, "colorname", ...etc)
   */
  fillColor?: string;

  /**
   * Set false if you want to create invisible polygon
   * (Invisible polygon is not clickable, default true)
   */
  visible?: boolean;

  /**
   * Hierarchy z-index
   */
  zIndex?: number;

  /**
   * Pass ILatLng[][] to create holes in polygon
   */
  addHole?: Array<Array<ILatLng>>;

  /**
   * Set true if you want to receive the POLYGON_CLICK event
   * (default: false)
   */
  clickable?: boolean;

  /**
   * Accept own properties
   * You can get the property later using `get()` method.
   */
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

**Confusingly**, this page [Google APIs for Android - PolygonOptions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolygonOptions) shows PolygonOptions as a class (which you can `new` up an instance of), but it's for Java not Javascript.